# How to open links in SSRS report from Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using iframes to house my SSRS reports.

I have a report that has links to external sites.

The expression is `="javascript:void(window.open('" + Fields!Url.Value + "', '', 'width=1000, height=800, top=0, left=0, resizable=yes'))"` which opens the link in new page or tab (requirement).

When I try to open those links from Report Manager, they work fine.

But when I am clicking the links from within the iframe, they don't work.

So, I need the links to work and also they need to open in new page or tab.

This, however, doesn't happen in Google Chrome. Issue occurs only in IE and Firefox.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own query.. :)

I added `&rc:LinkTarget=_blank` at the end of my iframe src.

Checked - it works fine.

Might be useful for some.

Answer (score 1):

I think `&rc:LinkTarget=_blank` is the ASP.NET code You are using in SSRS report. This will link Your page to new page.

Comment: I am not sure about that. I was going through this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188712.aspx) which helped me